# My background-image links and glyphicons stopped working in Heroku

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Although all my background images and glyphicons display correctly in my localhost, after my latest upload to Heroku, they stopped working. All other images display correctly.

My background images are defined custom.css.scss as 
    background-image: asset-data-url('bg-nav-dark.png');
I also tried 
    background-image:url('bg-nav.png');

My glyphicons in bootstrap.css are defined as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), etc.
```

When I inspect my home page in Heroku the console reveals these errors:

```
GET https://peaceful-harbor-2916.herokuapp.com/assets/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found) peaceful-harbor-2916.herokuapp.com/:11 
GET https://peaceful-harbor- 2916.herokuapp.com/assets/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found) application-a29ac562c89a1c46b8f0515885102bda.js:3509 
GET https://peaceful-harbor-2916.herokuapp.com/assets/bg-texture.png 404 (Not Found) application-a29ac562c89a1c46b8f0515885102bda.js:3509 
GET https://peaceful-harbor-2916.herokuapp.com/assets/bg-nav.png 404 (Not Found) application-a29ac562c89a1c46b8f0515885102bda.js:3509 
GET https://peaceful-harbor-2916.herokuapp.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff application-a29ac562c89a1c46b8f0515885102bda.js:3509
```

etc. etc.

(The above lines give me the idea that the precompiling places the assets in a places where Rails cannot find them afterwards...)
After pushing my code to Heroku I do a precompile and get this response:

```
$ heroku run rake assets:precompile Running `rake
assets:precompile` attached to terminal... up, run.3123 rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...":3,"sources":[": expected
"|", was ""bootstrap.css"..."   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

I am storing my images and fonts in these folders:

```
/app
  /assets
    /fonts
    / images
    / stylesheets
```

I do not know why, but the precompile results in the images appearing in the path
    /public
      /assets

In application.rb I have these lines:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true  # I have tried false as well
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
```

My production.rb contains
    config.serve_static_assets = true

My application.css contains:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require 'custom'
 *= require leaflet
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0'
gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap'
gem 'rails-assets-leaflet'
gem 'sass', '~>3.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'pg'
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
gem 'rake', '~> 10.3.2'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.6'
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'simplecov'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
ruby "2.1.4"
```

Please tell me what am I missing.

Comment: I have been able to solve this problem by removing my bootstrap files from my stylesheets folder. Application.css only refers to *= require bootstrap, and custom.css.scss has @import "bootstrap"; on top.